# Adding socket.io to a Node.js/Typescript project

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My project is created from a VS 2017 Typescript Basic Node.js Expresss 4 Application template. I added `socket.io` v2.0.3 via npm. I can compile. The moment I added `@types/socket.io` 1.4.30, I can't build anymore.  There are 97 errors, in node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts and Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts.

What have I done wrong?

---

Sample errors:

> Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'extensions' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeExtensions'.

And lots of `Duplicate identifier`:

> Build:Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.

Others:

> Build:'BuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
>
> Build:Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Server' and 'EventEmitter'.

Comment: Most likely you use incompatible versions of type definitions. Usually the problem happens because of some missing types. Please post the error messages here

Comment: @smnbbrv Added some error samples. Most of them are repetitive for different variable names.